# As a beginner, is cloning a local repo a good way to dev and deploy code on the same box? How?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

I'm new to Git and not an experienced programmer in general. I am using plain old Git and not messing around with GitHub. I have finally reached the point where I need to branch my repo for the first time, however I have the issue that the file I'm trying to branch is a web scraping script that I need to continue to work properly while I make changes to it. I read some about branching and did a test branch, and I noticed branching modifies the code in the working directory depending on which branch is checked out. So if I create a branch and check it out, once I modify it, the Windows Task Scheduler is going to try to run the modified file. So clearly I need a functional repo/version elsewhere on my machine that Task Scheduler can look at and I can push to.

Since I'm literally running a single file script, I could easily just copy it elsewhere and update the Task Scheduler to point there. Then I could replace the file any time I need to push a new "branch" (not really a branch anymore since I only work on one feature at a time). But I'm trying to be good and learn Git and do things properly.

So I guess my questions become: should I clone locally? And how is this achieved? I've tried reading about cloning but I'm confused by so much of the cloning documentation being focused on a remote repo like GitHub. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're only question is how to clone locally, then it's a duplicate question for which you can easily fine answers already on SO. But since you're asking a bit more, I'll not flag this as a dupe, but I will edit the question to make it unique.

Comment: This could be a good use for `git worktree`.

Comment: @hobbs: I absolutely agree that an experienced user should probably use worktrees for this specific use case, but if OP is trying to learn about cloning repository then the suggested workflow is reasonable.

Comment: @hobbs The problem with worktree is that you can't check out the same branch in both worktrees. Since Sunny is a beginner learning how to use git, getting good at dealing with remotes, pushing and pulling is far more valuable.

Comment: The issue here is that your git repository **is production**. You should have a separate clone that you work on, and then push somewhere, and this "somewhere" would be related to production. I would encourage you not to push *to* production, but instead have a triggering mechanism that reacts to you pushing to your central repository and then updating the production copy from it if the relevant branch was changed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen so you think my answers "a bit more advanced" section should be the main part of the answer? I was trying to keep things simple for a beginner both in git and programming.

Comment: Not necessarily. All in due time, I'd say, one step at a time and all that. Just make sure not to work directly on the production files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it's easy.

Yes for the reasons you stated: you're learning git. Cloning locally works identically to cloning a remote repo on GitHub or wherever, the only difference is that instead of a GitHub URL or SSH path, you use a directory path. In fact, when you clone a local repo, that existing repo will be considered **a remote** of the new one. And unlike a GitHub repo, you can manage both repos using the git CLI.

You can even make the new repo a remote of the original, pushing or pulling changes from either end. But if you're using this to get used to working with a GitHub repo, keep the relationship one-way, and do your development on the repo that is **downstream**, which is the one that you create as a clone of the one that is **upstream**, also the **origin** in this case. Have Task Scheduler execute from the upstream repo's worktree.

You want to have your setup end up looking like this:

```
origin/upstream:       path/to/origin/script.py
                                      README.md
                                      .git
                        
clone/downstream:      path/to/clone/script.py
                                     README.md
                                     .git
```

Try not to get confused by all the terms, they are just naming conventions.  The `path/to/origin/` repo will variously be called an *upstream*, the *origin*, a *remote* of the `path/to/clone/` repo.  And no, the directories, of the repos do not have to be named "origin" or "clone" -- the paths and files above are just examples.

#### steps

1. Move your existing repo to where you want to run your scheduled task from. If it's already there, great.
2. On your command line, `cd` to the directory within which you want the new clone directory to go.
3. Execute the following:

   ```sh
   git clone path/to/origin
   ```

   using the actual path to wherever you put it in step 1.

   This mimics the  `git clone github.com/path/to/origin` command you'd use to clone a GitHub repo.

   It will create a new directory in the current directory with the same name as the directory you are cloning. If for some reason you need it to have a differnent name, e.g. if the origin and the clone are in the same parent directory, use this command instead:

   ```
   git clone path/to/origin path/to/clone
   ```

   The new directory will contain a git repo (the `.git` dir) and all the files in the main branch will be checked out.

   If you mess up, no big deal. Delete the newly created directory (not the origin!), and start over.
4. You can confirm the relationship between the two repos by `cd`-ing into the clone directory and typing:

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```

   You will see the remote was given the name "origin" by default. It's just a convention as I said, and you can actually change the name, but as a beginner it's best to stick to the defaults.
5. To see all the branches in both repos, and to confirm the tracking relationship between the main/master branches on the two repos, type:

   ```
   git branch -vva
   ```

#### basic workflow

- do all your work in the clone repo
- push new commits, new branches, etc to your remote (aka upstream, origin) repo as you need to, e.g.:

  ```
  git push
  ```

  You don't need to specify the push destination when you're in a branch that has a remote tracking branch (what you saw in step 5 above).

  This step simply syncs whatever you push into the remote git repo database. It DOES NOT update what is checked out into its worktree. In other words, your scheduled task will keep executing the same version of the code it was running before.
- To update what your scheduled task executes, `cd` to that repo and execute a git command to checkout whatever version of the code you want it to execute going forward. If it's just whatever is the latest commit is on the branch it already has checkout out, it's a simple:

  ```
  git pull
  ```

#### a bit more advanced

If you want to better mimic setups that rely on central repo server (such as GitHub), you would have three repos related like so:

```
           origin/upstream
                |  | 
          ______|  |_____
          |              |
     dev clone           |
                     deploy clone  <-- your scheduled task runs in this repo
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This comment does not add anything to the answer, but I refuse to let my appreciation of an answer with so much effort be clicking a little checkmark. Inigo, I appreciate your detailed explanation when you could have simply left it at at single paragraph and the code example. Had you not included the "basic workflow" section, I probably would have spun my wheels there for a while too.

Comment: My pleasure. I was also writing for everyone else that has this question in the future, because I think it is a common case. Hope it's all working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try cloning locally using bare repository ?
you can read abt it more at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bare-repositories-in-git/
ex-

```
cd ${HOME}
mkdir FileName.git
cd FileName.git
git init --bare
```

Now you can write your stuff in this repo
then you can go to any other location say /tmp

```
cd /tmp
git clone ${HOME}/FileName.git
```

so you can use you own directory like a remote repo

Comment: This might be a good approach for the "central" repo I have in my "a bit more advanced" section in my answer. But for a beginner I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

> should I clone locally?

No. I'm going to push back against Inigo's answer. The reason is that pushing to a non-bare repo is just too fraught with pitfalls.

I suggest that even for a beginner the right way is the one that is glanced at at the end of Inigo's answer: push the deployment folder to a remote repo as its deployment branch, clone the remote repo to another folder, and then in that folder make a development branch and experiment there.

This way, you push the development branch to the remote as a backup while experimenting, and if an experiment succeeds you push the development repo and then fetch into the deployment repo and merge the development branch into the deployment branch.

This is the clean way to use Git. Yes, it presumes you have an Internet connection at the time you deploy a new version, but surely that's not too much to ask.

Comment: Matt, I don't quite understand why it is not okay to have the repo in two locations on the same machine. You are certainly right about the bare repo comment because when I do exactly as Inigo has suggested, pushing gives an error too long to include here but a snippet it "By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent..." Instead of pushing, I just pulled from the deployment main. I definitely have no clue what I'm doing, but that's how you learn and I'm open to explanations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's fine to have two clones of a repo on the same machine, and that's what I'm suggesting you should do. What I'm arguing is not so fine is putting yourself in the position of pushing from one local repo to another local repo — for exactly the reason suggested by the warning you quoted.

Comment: matt, I suppose I'm not understanding the correct way to use a clone. The setup I've ended up with is preventing me from pushing or pulling, but what's the point of a clone if you're not passing information one way or the other? Is there something I should do to avoid the error about a non-bare repository? I would guess I should be using a bare repository. This is presumably my clone since I would want the main/origin repo to have the full revision info associated with it.

Comment: I do not know what you _have_ done (the setup I've ended up with). I've answered with what I think you _should_ do. You clearly don't agree with me, and that's fine; I've said my bit, which is all I wanted to do.

Comment: matt, it seems my phrasing may have been poor. My questions were not an attack on you, they were legitimate things I don’t understand. I’m sorry that’s I’ve upset you. I’ve been reading about git today and it seems I need to just keep going. I won’t try to drag you into walking me through it. I’ll post a different question if I can’t figure it out. I do very much appreciate your help.